# Edit shows expected code with a different format than what it really is

Tags: bug, edits, code-formatting

I'm using Google Chrome on Android 10 - Samsung Galaxy A30s.

When looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65122251/5675325)

[image]

We can see the first code block has a specific indentation. Then, when clicking to edit

[image]

The expected result looks better (the ngOnInit appears closer to the edge than it really is).

---

### Edit

Now when going through different answers in Google Chrome on my Windows 10 machine, found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/176921/5675325) with similar problem in the code.

When looking at the real answer there's an extra empty paragraph in the code

[image]

When we're editing, the expected result looks like this (it doesn't have that extra paragraph)

[image]

Comment: It's a snippet, not normal code. That's the border width used on a Stack Snippet.

Comment: @CodyGray Is it normal being different in both sides?

Comment: That makes it harder to edit to the proper format  if the expected result doesn't really match the reality

Comment: I think it is caused (in some way) by the  over-indented code (it has 6 spaces before it, while the HTML part of the snippet is indented with 4 and renders correctly).

Comment: @FZs sure but interesting how in one place the spaces are picked up and in the other no

Comment: Bugs are often... *strange*.

Comment: Confirmed (Firefox 83.0 on [Ubuntu MATE 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_MATE#Releases)) (Focal Fossa)). The problem disappears if the extra 2 spaces indent in the first snippet is removed (and it is not caused by the extra 4 spaces on a separate line before the snippets).

Comment: Using 2 extra spaces indent (divisible by 4, for a total of 8 spaces indent) does not help - the first line, `ngOnInit() {`, is still not indented in the preview.

Comment: I ran into a similar problem with syntax highlighting of the first line (in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42493017)). Using "```lang-html" instead of 4 space indent was a way to fix it. Is there a corresponding meta question?

Comment: @PeterMortensen not that I know of. Not sure if it'd really make sense since it's shown only in SO